# Removing space from a string and coverting it to camel case format in C

Tags: c

I have a program that I have not written. It is supposed to remove white spaces from the string, and turn it into a camel case format. For example:

Input: Hello World! 
Supposed to give: helloWorld! 
Now I have a couple of questions about this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *convert(char *f) {

    char *save = f; 
    char *output = f;  
    int in_a_word = 1; 

    while(isspace(*f)) f++; 
    for(; *f; f++) {

            if(isspace(*f)) in_a_word = 0;
            else
            {
                if(in_a_word) {
                *output= tolower(*f);

                }
                else {
                    *output = toupper(*f);

                }
                in_a_word = 1;
                output++;


            }
        *output= '\0';
        }
    return save;

    }


int main(void) {

char str[] = "  Hello World\t";
printf("Modified: -->%s<---\n", convert(str));
getchar();
}
```

My questions:

```
char *save = f; 
char *output = f;
```

If I understand correctly, both of them are supposed to point to f. I have written an experiment program:

```
int main(void) {

char *s = "    Hello";
char *ment = s;
printf("Original:\n-->%s, %p<---\n-->%s, %p<---\n\n", s,s,ment,ment);
while(isspace(*s)) s++;
printf("Modified:\n-->%s, %p<---\n-->%s, %p<---", s,s,ment,ment);
getchar();
}
```

In this program I have saved the address of s in ment. When I use the first printf, it shows that they are completely equal, and they point to the same location. I make a little modification on s. This removes all the space from s, but ment stayed the same. Even their location changed.

Going back to the original program. In the convert function we are returning save, but it has not been modified. So my question is: can anyone explain why we are returning save? And/or which source material should I refer to. I read a couple of books on pointers, but none has mentioned this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the convert function we are returning save, but it has not been modified. So my question is: can anyone explain why we are returning save?

`save` is to store the original location of the string. Note that `output` pointer is modified within the function:

```
output++; // output pointer has been modified to point to next character
```

So you can't return `output` itself - you want to return the original location of the string.

In other words, there are distinct purposes of the two pointers in that function:

- `output` is to modify the string content (this pointer changes throughout the function)
- `save` is to store the original string location (this pointer isn't changed within the function) and for returning it to the calling function

Comment: But why is it good if I have the original location? Based on the program I have written (the short one), ment isn't at all altered. At the start they both point to the same location. But after I modified s, s's content and location changed. Based on the same logic, I have saved the location of f in save, but isn't it supposed to point to where f originally pointed, i.e the original string? Sorry for the bad explanation, I'm just starting out in pointers.

Comment: because your `convert` function returns a char pointer. Without saving `f` you will end up returning the end of string (which points to null character) instead of the whole string (which starts from the beginning)